# jQuery on chnage collect all checkbox names and parse it as string

Tags: jquery, checkbox, each

I'm trying to do the following:

Here is my html:

```
<p id="textList"></p>
<div id="userList">
  <input type="checkbox" data-name="John" name="users[]" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" data-name="Peter" name="users[]" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" data-name="Mike" name="users[]" value="3">
</div>
```

and this is the javascript I got so far

```
$('#userList').on('change', 'input', function() {
    $.each($('#userList input'), function(i,v) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
          ...

        }
    });
})
```

When the checkbox is checked and need to go through each one of them and append to #textList all the names from data-name, coma separated. Like (John, Peter), if checkbox is unchecked, remove the name from #textList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by using `.map` to loop over checked checkbox and return only its data's name, like following code :

```
$('#userList').on('change', 'input', function(e) {

   var names = $(e.delegateTarget).find(':checkbox:checked').map(function(v, i) {
     return $(i).data('name');
   }).get();

  $('#textList').text(names);

});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/bd9Ld2pv/)